# select query in sqlplus(oracle) not working?

Tags: oracle

I have oracle database server. I use sqlplus for select some infomation of database. But it seem not working ([result like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0Aqw.png)) ? It will alway display "2" for all query "select".
Something is went wrong?

Comment: That is how statements can be entered over multiple lines. To run your query end a line with a semi-colon `;`.

Comment: @Brian `;` is just the default [`sqlterminator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqpug/SET-system-variable-summary.html#GUID-5D91A9A9-13A2-4F62-B02A-AD2F3AFF8BB7), although to be fair nobody ever changes it. The [`/` character](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqpug/slash.html#GUID-F5EEC10C-6E74-4CCE-A196-C591F83C3D44) doesn't change though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you try using statement terminator, i.e. `;` at the end of statement. Something like

```
select sysdate from dual;
```

Answer (score 2):

sqlplus prompt expect multi-line query if you are not giving the query terminator and shows number. Hence you were getting 2 as 2nd line number.

Answer (score 1):

its not showing you the output rather its making the cursor go to next line which is 2.